# Hiding .DS_Store in ColdFusion Built-in Server

Tags: tomcat, coldfusion

By default, the ColdFusion built in Server shows .DS_Store files on MacOS. Is there a setting to hide these?

[image]

Comment: The directory listing is not so much a part of ColdFusion as Tomcat. Have you tried [specifying a security constraint (tomcat 7, thus javaee6)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncbk/index.html) for `*/.DS_store` in web.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DS_Store files are automatically created by Mac OSX Finder in browsed directories. These files contain information about system configuration. Read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.DS_Store).

Here is how you can remove it

1. Select Applications > Utilities to launch Terminal.
2. Enter the following UNIX command: **sudo find / -name ".DS_Store" -depth -exec rm {} \;**
3. When prompted for a password enter your Mac OS X Administrator
   password.

Comment: I don't want to remove them, I just don't want them served by the web server